# Contar con Python las letras de cada palabra de una cadena

Tags: python-3.x, string, funciones

Hace poco que inicié en esto y estoy teniendo problemas con este programa. Tengo que escribir una función que reciba una cadena y regrese el número de palabras en la cadena que tienen 4 o más caracteres.

ejemplo:

> cadena=" las palabras de internet son cadenas"
>
> numero de palabras que tienen 4 o + caracteres: 3

Estaba pensando en usar `str.split()`, pero no sé si voy en buen camino.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te puede funcionar de esta manera igual

```
def cuatro_o_mas(cadena):
    _a=cadena.split()
    i=0
    for x in _a:
        if(len(x)>=4):
            i+=1
    return i
print(cuatro_o_mas("las palabras de internet son cadenas"))
```

Output:`3`

Comment: muchas gracias ,si funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar list comprehensions

```
def cuatro_o_mas(cadena):
    return len([x for x in cadena.split() if len(x) >= 4])
```

Comment: Esta respuesta quedaría mucho mas completa si le explicas a OP como funciona el método que le muestras ;)

Comment: Es necesario explicar el código no soló por el OP, sino para que uno mismo reflexione al momento de dar la respuesta... por ejemplo que hace ¿`if len(x) >= 4`? evalúa si `len(x) >= 4` es cierto o no... en esencia es un `booleano` entonces en cada palabra contenida en la cadena `cadena.split()`... se hace un chequeo `True, False, True, ...` sí tenemos una lista de booleanos... `Python` permite sumarlos es decir los trata como `1 ó 0` en tal sentido, la lista comprimida podría quedar así `sum([len(palabra) >= 4 for palabra in cadena.split()])`

Comment: @HubertRonald. Me gustaría que publiques tu propia respuesta, explicando más en detalle esto de "booleanos son números" en Python.

Answer (score 0):

### Consideraciones

Esta respuesta amplia el comentario vertido en una respuesta previa, por recomendación de @CandidMoe.

### Booleanos como números

El código del **OP** muestra que si la `suma es mayor e igual a cuatro` se agrega una unidad al contador `i` es decir, si no se cumple lo anterior `no se agrega nada` a `i` o expresado de otra manera, se `suma cero` al contador `i`.

Sobre lo anterior **Python** permite realizar operaciones numéricas con booleanos:

```
print(True + True)     # se imprime 2
print(True + False)    # se imprime 1
print(True * 5)        # se imprime 5
print(False * 20)      # se imprime 0
```

Es decir `True` equivale a `1` mientras que `False` se le da el tratamiento de `0`.

Sobre lo anterior hay que hacer una precisión... la función `bool` de **Python** permite convertir cualquier número de tipo entero, flotante y complejo a `True` salvo el `cero` que es `False`:

```
# Enteros
print(bool(1))          # se imprime True
print(bool(-20))        # se imprime True
print(bool(0))          # se imprime False

# Flotantes
print(bool(3.4))        # se imprime True
print(bool(-1.7))       # se imprime True
print(bool(0.000))      # se imprime False

# Complejos
print(bool(3+4j))       # se imprime True
print(bool(-7-5j))      # se imprime True
print(bool(0+0j))       # se imprime False
```

### Lista Comprimida

Hay una `cadena` y con el método `split` se convierte en una lista y a partir de ella se puede iterar

```
cadena = "las palabras de internet son cadenas"
contar = 0
for palabra in cadena.split():
    if len(palabra)>= 4:
        contar = contar + 1

print(contar) # Resultado 3
```

Ahora bien, la siguiente `expresión` nos indica si es cierto o no, que cada palabra en la lista `cadena.split()` tiene una longitud `>=` a 4 letras

```
expresion = [len(palabra) >= 4 for palabra in cadena.split()]
```

Nótese que la lista `expresion` contiene boolenaos y la cantidad de verdaderos es igual al resultado de `print(contar)`

```
print(cadena.split()) # ['las', 'palabras', 'de', 'internet', 'son', 'cadenas']
print(expresion)      # [False, True, False, True, False, True] -> 3 verdaderos
```

Por tanto se aplica `sum` a la lista `expresion`

```
print(sum(expresion)) # Resultado 3
```

### Acotación: Generadora

No obstante el resultado anterior, si se va aplicar `sum` a una lista que se genera mediante `list comprehensions` no hay necesidad de emplear los `[ ]` porque [se recomienda usar sólo la expresión generadora](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-wrong-use-cases-of-python-list-comprehensions-e8455fb75692), ya que produce valores de `uno en uno`:

```
contar = sum(len(palabra) >= 4 for palabra in cadena.split())
print(contar)            # Resultado 3
```

### Posibles Aplicaciones

Saber que porcentaje de veces se repite una palabra en un párrafo o texto, digamos por ejemplo.. qué cantidad de veces, empleo la palabra `'que'`, el **OP** en su `pregunta`

```
preg = """\
Hace poco que inicié en esto y estoy teniendo problemas con este programa.
Tengo que escribir una función que reciba una cadena y regrese
el número de palabras en la cadena que tienen 4 o más caracteres.
""".split()

print(f"{100 * sum('que' in pal.lower() for pal in preg) / len(preg):.3} %")
# 10.8 %
```

> Nota: idea tomada de [Python Booleans as Numbers](https://realpython.com/python-boolean/#:%7E:text=Booleans%20are%20numeric%20types%2C%20and,%3D%3D%201%20%2C%20it%20returns%20False.&text=Since%200%20is%20less%20than%201%20%2C%20a%20%3C%201%20returns%20True%20.)