# ¿ Cómo puedo crear un condicional con dos condiciones de dos variables diferentes en una sola?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, programación-funcional

De ante mano doy las gracias si me podrían orientar en mi función:

Necesito crear una función que cumpla una condición.

Requiero hacer un condicional en donde `X` es un `array` de dos columnas y 20 filas, y la condición es que dado `t` que es un `array` con dos números:

Ponga `0` si la **primera variable de `X` es menor el primer elemento en `t`** y que la **segunda variable en `X` sea mayor que el segundo elemento en `t`**. En otro caso `1`.

El código que tengo es así:

```
for col in X:
   y_new= X[col].apply(lambda x: 0 if X[:,0] < t[0] else (0 if X[:,1]> t[1] else 1))
```

```
X
array([[0.5 , 0.65],
       [0.75, 0.34],
       [0.37, 0.5 ],
       [0.57, 0.74],
       [1.  , 0.69],
       [0.1 , 0.61],
       [0.04, 0.36],
       [0.56, 0.45],
       [0.46, 0.01],
       [0.46, 0.97],
       [0.26, 0.83],
       [0.47, 0.01],
       [0.34, 1.  ],
       [0.85, 0.41],
       [0.  , 0.72],
       [0.66, 0.08],
       [0.3 , 0.19],
       [0.71, 0.  ],
       [0.3 , 0.77],
       [0.17, 0.96]])
```

Pero no me funciona. ¿Cómo puedo arreglarla?

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías poner  cual es la variable `X`?

Comment: ¿Te da algún error?¿el resultado no es el que esperas?, por que dices que no funciona?

Comment: Listo ya la edite de nuevo. Gracias

Comment: Me genera un error : IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Comment: En python no existen los arrays, solo las listas. Además las listas no tienen una propiedad `apply`

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo así sin el apply, pero tampoco me funcionafor i in X: 
  y_new= [0 if X[i:,0] < t[0] and X[i:,1]> t[1] else 1]

Comment: El resultado de la condcion quieres que reemplaze a los valores de X o que X conserve sus valores?

Comment: que cree un vector de 0 y 1, 0 donde se cumpla la condición con las dos variables y 1  en otro caso

Comment: en python vanilla no hay arrays, pero ese formato de array([[]]) me parece que es el de numpy.array()

Comment: Sí es un numpy.array()

Comment: cuando dices "primera variable de X" te refieres a la columna? y con que ponga 0 o 1 te refieres a mostrarlo en pantalla?
quieres que esto suceda con cada columna con una iteración?

Comment: quiero crear una dummy  en donde sea 0 si los valores de la columna 1 son menores a 0.5 y a su vez que los valores de la columna 2 sean mayores a 0.3.

Comment: @Jen dado que aceptaste mi respuesta y todas son validas, votaré a favor al resto (debido a que no puedes votar a favor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Respuesta

Aquí una solución usando solamente `numpy`, la variable `t` es cortesía de @Christian

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0.5 , 0.65], ..., [0.17, 0.96]])
t = np.array([0.5, 0.3]) # Cortesia de @Christian

X = X.transpose()
Y = ~ ( (X[0] < t[0]) & (X[1] > t[1]) ) * 1
print(Y)
# array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

### Explicación

La idea central reside en `X.transpose()` es decir convertir las "columnas" en "filas" para operarlas más convenientemente en `numpy`

```
array([[0.5 , 0.75, 0.37, 0.57, 1.  , 0.1 , 0.04, 0.56, 0.46, 0.46, 0.26,
        0.47, 0.34, 0.85, 0.  , 0.66, 0.3 , 0.71, 0.3 , 0.17],
       [0.65, 0.34, 0.5 , 0.74, 0.69, 0.61, 0.36, 0.45, 0.01, 0.97, 0.83,
        0.01, 1.  , 0.41, 0.72, 0.08, 0.19, 0.  , 0.77, 0.96]])
```

Chequemos que implica esta expresión

```
(X[0] < t[0]) & (X[1] > t[1])
# array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False,
#        True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,
#        True,  True])
```

Quiere decir que si estos límites se cumplen deben ser `Verdadero`... pero se está pidiendo que esto sea `cero` o dicho de otra forma `Falso` es por eso que se emplea el operador `~` para negar la expresión.

```
 ~ ( (X[0] < t[0]) & (X[1] > t[1]) )
 # array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
 #        False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,
 #        False, False])
```

Finalmente, la expresión se multiplica por 1 (`*1`) para convertir los booleanos a número

```
 Y = ~ ( (X[0] < t[0]) & (X[1] > t[1]) ) * 1
```

> **Nota:** En esta respuesta [Contar con Python las letras de cada palabra de una cadena](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/450026/contar-con-python-las-letras-de-cada-palabra-de-una-cadena/455627#455627) comento más sobre este aspecto

Comment: Esta es la lógica que quería entender, le agradezco mucho. Y le agradezco a todos por su apoyo si pudiera aceptar todas lo haría... Muchas gracias por el tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

primero hay que recordar que en Python no existen los *arrays*, salvo que estés trabajando con `numpy` y la variable `X` sea de tipo `numpy.array`, segundo las listas no tienen un metodo `apply()` solo los `DataFrames` y no estas trabajando con uno. Por ultimo tu expresión *lambda* esta mal, incluido `X[:,0]` (no se para que haces eso). Para tu problema vamos a solucionarlo utilizando la función `map()` junto a una expresión lambda, para acceder a cada elemento usaremos la sintaxis `X[0],X[1]` para acceder al primer y segundo elemento correspondientemente.

la funcion `map()` nos devolverá una lista con los valores obtenidos de acuerdo a la expresión lambda pasada

Por lo que veo comparas con `t`, por lo tanto si dices que debe ser mayor a `0.5` y menor a `0.3` `t=[0.5,0.3]`

```py
t = [0.5,0.3]

#pondra 0 si el primer valor es menor que 0.5 el segundo es mayor 0.3, de lo contrario 1
y_new = map(lambda x: 0 if x[0]<0.5 and x[1]>0.3 else 1, X)

#es lo mismo que
#y_new = map(lambda x: 0 if x[0]<t[0] and x[1]>t[1] else 1, X)

#para ver sus elementos lo convertimos a lista
y_new = list(y_new)

#imprimimos
print(y_new)
```

Dando como resultado

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

En un comentario dijiste que era un Numpy.array(), en este caso también funciona la expresión lambda :)

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0.5 , 0.65],
       [0.75, 0.34],
       [0.37, 0.5 ],
       [0.57, 0.74],
       [1.  , 0.69],
       [0.1 , 0.61],
       [0.04, 0.36],
       [0.56, 0.45],
       [0.46, 0.01],
       [0.46, 0.97],
       [0.26, 0.83],
       [0.47, 0.01],
       [0.34, 1.  ],
       [0.85, 0.41],
       [0.  , 0.72],
       [0.66, 0.08],
       [0.3 , 0.19],
       [0.71, 0.  ],
       [0.3 , 0.77],
       [0.17, 0.96]])


y_new = map(lambda x: 0 if x[0]<0.5 and x[1]>0.3 else 1, X)

#es lo mismo que
#y_new = map(lambda x: 0 if x[0]<t[0] and x[1]>t[1] else 1, X)

y_new = list(y_new)
print(y_new)
```

**Salida**

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Si quieres obtener los su valor *boleano* podemos hacerlo transformándolo con la función `bool()`, esto mediante una compresión de lista

```py
y_new = [bool(val) for val in y_new]
print(y_new)
```

**Salida**

```
[True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False]
```

Y como te dije en un comentario puedes negar eso

```py
y_new = [not bool(val) for val in y_new]
print(y_new)
```

**Salida**

```
[False, False, True, False, False, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, True, True]
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124904/discussion-on-answer-by-christian--como-puedo-crear-un-condicional-con-dos-cond).

Answer (score 1):

Entendiendo que lo que quieres es lo siguiente:
teniendo un array `t = [m1, m2]` y un array `X = [xn, yn]` crear una función que devuelva una lista de ceros y unos la cual se genera por comparar cada columna de `X` con sus respectivos valores en `t`, entonces:

```
from numpy import array

X = array([[0.5 , 0.65],
       [0.75, 0.34],
       [0.37, 0.5 ],
       [0.57, 0.74],
       [1.  , 0.69],
       [0.1 , 0.61],
       [0.04, 0.36],
       [0.56, 0.45],
       [0.46, 0.01],
       [0.46, 0.97],
       [0.26, 0.83],
       [0.47, 0.01],
       [0.34, 1.  ],
       [0.85, 0.41],
       [0.  , 0.72],
       [0.66, 0.08],
       [0.3 , 0.19],
       [0.71, 0.  ],
       [0.3 , 0.77],
       [0.17, 0.96]])


t = array([0.40,0.20])  #valores para prueba

def comparaArray(arr, values):
    resultado = []
    for n1, n2 in arr:
        print(n1 ,' < ',values[0],' and ',n2,' > ',values[1])
        if (n1 < values[0] and n2 > values[1]):
            resultado+=[0]
            print('Agregado al resultado: 0')
        else:
            resultado+=[1]
            print('Agregado al resultado: 1')
    return resultado

print(comparaArray(X,t))
#[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Lo que hice fue deconstruir `arr` en dos variables `n1`, `n2`, donde son respectivamente los valores de cada columna de `X` y compararlas con los valores datos en el array `t`.

Espero haber entendido bien el asunto y darte una buena respuesta ~

*pd: ignoren la cantidad excesiva de prints solo fue para probar la logica*

Comment: Sí, está perfecto, tengo una pregunta, si funciona pero si quiero intentar hacerlo de otra manera con un condicional que me genere booleanos, es decir false 0 true 1. Cómo sería?

Comment: es decir que la lista tenga valores booleanos donde 0//false y 1//true?
solo tendrias que cambiar la condición a: 
if (n1 < values[0] and n2 > values[1]):
            resultado+=[False]

        else:
            resultado+=[True]

si no estas tan seguro del resultado podrias hacer un type(resultado[0]) y veras que es de tipo booleano

Comment: No hay una forma en donde se pueda hacer el condicional y que python genere los booleanos por defecto? sin que yo los deba de establecer?

Comment: @Jen no, pero.. para que quieres eso?, el valor `0` es un valor *falsy* por lo que sera evaluado como `False` y el valor `1` es un valor *truthy*; evaluado como `True`, si lo deseas al revés puedes negar una expresión

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Christian buen punto, habia olvidado que python evalua 1 y 0 como True, False, respectivamente (js me esta afectando jajaja)

Comment: @AnkiJedi jajaja, yo respondería mas cosas de JS pero la mayoría es de web y me da pereza montar una web

Comment: @Christian Joder tambien sabes js? te podria consultar algo por privado que estoy tratando de hacer?

Comment: @AnkiJedi Hee... si, por supuesto [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124840/hola)